# Using reflection to create object with parameters in constructor

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I can not understand the following code:

```
Constructor<T>[] constructors = (Constructor<T>[]) clazz.getConstructors();  
for(int i = 0; i < constructors.length; i++){  
  Constructor<T> constructor = constructors[i];    
  if (constructor.getParameterTypes().length>0){    
    T instanceObject = constructor.newInstance(new Object[constructor.getParameterTypes().length]);  
        break;  
  }  

}
```

Have omitted `try/catch` and other stuff for clarity.
I can not understand how this works: `T instanceObject = constructor.newInstance(new Object[constructor.getParameterTypes().length]);`
It calls a constructor that has parameters, but passes as arguments `Object`?
How does this work? Passing `Object` independent of the actual formal parameters?

Comment: you need all arguments to be non-primitive and the c-tor to make sense w/ having all parameters null

Comment: @bestsss:`Individual parameters are automatically unwrapped to match primitive formal parameters` from Javadoc

Comment: Jim, except null is unwrapped to NPE. I know the spec and even the impl, really no need to quote. The unwrapping is simple: `Integer.intValue()`, `Double.doubleValue()` - hence the NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It attempts to pass dummy parameters which are all `null`. This can give you an Object but it doesn't mean it will be a useful one. ;)

I am not sure why it skips zero length constructors as this is the one constructor you are likely to be able to pass no arguments successfully.

Comment: also can lead to NPE if any of the arguments are primitive

Comment: it could lead to an NPE even if the arguments are not primitive but expect you to pass it something. ;) I assume the outer loop catches exceptions and keeps trying if it gets one.

Comment: I mean it won't even get to the c-tor. Of course, any arbitrary data can lead to errors but at w/ primitives the c-tor won't even be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

An array of objects with number of elements equal to number of parameters in the constructor, hence:

```
new Object[constructor.getParameterTypes().length])
```